# How to initialise a random matrix in R with no duplicates in the columns but duplicates allowed in rows

Tags: r, matrix, random

I would like to create a matrix in R, say 1000 by 10, and each column is a random sample without replacement of 1000 numbers between 1 and 1000. I would like this random sample 10 times, one for each column in the matrix.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `replicate(10, sample(1:1000))` ?

Comment: Exactally. Thank you!